# Laravel 4.2 selection from one to many relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables like this:

Events with columns
id
name
description

Events_Recurrents
id
start_date
fk_event

I would like to know how can i get for example all instances of recurrent of a given event that is after some date, or before some date, but using eloquent orm ? Using L 4.2

Thank you,
moz

Comment: Why don't you read the docs? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#one-to-many

Comment: I did that and even tried a few scenarios and after that not succeeding I am asking here, I even have the relationship models defined http://laravel.io/bin/d9kOW

Comment: Example: `EventModel::findOrFail(3)->recurents()->where('start_date', '>=', '2014-02-11')->get();`

Comment: Please show what you have tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: I managed to do something simillar `$events = EventRecurents::where('start_date', '>', 2014-02-11')->where('fk_event', 2)->get(); ` but now  I am thinking if each event would be attached to User table one to many relationships, would it be any way I could get for a given user his next events?

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple where-statement would do the trick:

```
$date = new DateTime('02/31/2011');
$eventsRecurrents = EventsRecurrents::where('start_date', '<', $date)->get();
```